# What does the JVM do after finishing an application?

Tags: java, spring

I want to know what JVM do when finish the application. Did it run `System.exit()` and what is different between `System.exit()` and `SystemExiter()`?

Comment: The JVM shuts down. It doesn't need to call System.exit(), since the JVM is not a Java program. Also, SystemExiter seems to be in no way related to anything (it's a Spring class?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How exactly the JVM shuts down will differ between implementations. Remember that a JVM is not written in Java and will not call `System.exit()` to end itself.

[`SystemExiter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/SystemExiter.html) is a Spring interface that abstracts calls to `System.exit()`. Applications can use that interface rather than calling `System.exit()` directly, allowing the behaviour to be modified during tests. If a class were to call `System.exit()` during a test, it would end the test cycle because the JVM would shut down. Example:

```
public class SomeClass {

  private SystemExiter exiter; // inject this or accept in constructor

  public void someMethod() {
    // ...

    exiter.exit(1);
  }
}
```

In a production system, you could use the [`JvmSystemExiter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/JvmSystemExiter.html) implementation to actually shut the VM. In a test, you'd probably mock the `SystemExiter` interface and check that `exit()` was called.

Comment: You stole my comment! ;)

Comment: In my application Spring batch, I run multiple jobs form a single job. That need SystemExister method. If it is not include only a job run. Please explain how SystemExister work. Thank you very much.